# insert, delete etc. keys not working on Cherry Strait keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard

I got a Cherry Strait USB wired keyboard for xmas and I've been unable to get several keys working under Ubuntu 10.10 or Win XP. There are a few keys. including the Print Screen key, insert, end, delete, pg up, pg down and home. I've not been able to identify any others that aren't working.

I'm not sure as to the best approach to determine what's wrong. Is there any way to confirm whether there is any output from the keyboard in response to pressing those keys, ideally in Ubuntu as that's where I spend most of my time so that I know if it's a fault with the device itself?

(I've tried different USB ports and also hitting those keys whilst in the Keyboard Shortcuts app, no response to these keys)

Comment: Try running `xev` and pressing those keys (and some others, too). If you don't get any output, the keyboard may be defective. If you do, then there are some settings you can make.

Comment: done - no output for those all and only keys I mentioned, plenty of output for the other keys I tried. Looks like a defective keyboard then...